# Is it possible to add a hyperlink url to a XamarinForms Alert Box in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently opening an alert with a button press, and would really like a clickable url hyperlink like so:

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("Top 100 University Help",
        "Did you attend one of these universities?\n\nhttps://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/rankings",
        "OK");
}
```

Would it be possible for a tap on it to open the url in safari? Would it be bad form to do so?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible. Not on all platforms, I think and certainly not with default Xamarin.Forms code. You will need custom renderers. I think, if at all possible, you would make your life a lot easier by solving this differently.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis what would be your suggestion, something regarding a web view?

Comment: I think that is dependent on what you are trying to do. I can't tell from this single line of code what the idea behind the whole app is :)